# Не запускается приложение с Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Использовал в приложении Google Maps. На эмуляторе с поддержкой Google APIs 2.2 всё работает. На девайс не устанавливается. Ошибка `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`. Я новичок и не сталкивался с этим раньше.

Comment: @Kaminskiy, про какой девайс речь? Android-based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка возникает в том случае, когда устройство не поддерживает необходимый Google API. Нужна [Maps External Library](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html). Поскольку библиотека карт  - это собственность Google, она не входит в образ системы по умолчанию, вместо этого Google создает специальный образ, включающий требуемые библиотеки. Чтобы библиотека была установлена, производители телефонов должны купить лицензию, а если библиотека не установлена, приложение работать не будет.